# How to scan and compare images in different flipperView?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a game in words.
The meaning of the game is as follows:

1. There is a picture of designating word. eg word - ball
2. We offer an letter.

I have 4 flipper.

```
reels[0] = (ViewFlipper)v.findViewById(R.id.oneFlipper);
reels[1] = (ViewFlipper)v.findViewById(R.id.twoFlipper);
reels[2] = (ViewFlipper)v.findViewById(R.id.threeFlipper);
reels[3] = (ViewFlipper)v.findViewById(R.id.fourFlipper);
```

Each flipper has 4 pictures with letters.

At the bottom I made a button with the letters.

```
letters[0] = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.first_letter);     
letters[1] = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.second_letter);
letters[2] = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.third_letter);     
letters[3] = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.four_letter);
```

When you press the button with the letter, the flipper is selected suitable image with the letter.

Then I did a test word. If the word is incorrectly collected, each incorrect letter in the word is encircled by a red frame and disappears.

But there was a problem. If a word has the same letter (baLL), the check can not occur correctly. I need a method that will scan and compare images on the flippers.

How to scan and compare images in different flipperView?