# Is it possible to make two buttons with same id in one layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Is it possible to make two buttons with same id in one layout?

I tried to do through the tag `<include>`, but does not work for the listener one of the buttons

Comment: If a company wants to offer the same perks to some employees, do they get same employee **id**?

Comment: this condition can not be undone? tag <include> allows you to show
button twice, but the listener will only work on one.

Comment: why you want two buttons with the same id? You want call the same function in the onclick ?

Comment: No, but it's possible to use the same exact listener on two different buttons, thus avoiding code duplication. Is that what you want by any chance?

Comment: In that case you don't need two different buttons. anyway you can: button2.PerformClick(); in button1 listener.

Comment: I make the game, "the words" and to use the letters of a button. When you push the button, it appears in the word.

The game has the word verification. If you have the same letters in a word (eg BALL), then the check is triggered is not true, because the letters L different id. 
The same id facilitate this task

here more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617910/how-to-scan-and-compare-images-in-different-flipperview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** 2016:

This is no longer possible,android lint checks prevent you from adding same ids in the same xml file.
A work-around would be to use the `include` tag to include other xmls with repeating ids.
Nevertheless this is an approach that should be avoided.

**OLD ANSWER**

TL:DR; You can have only distince ids in a View Container,if you create one more container,you can refer to it using `parent.findViewById(R.id.child_id)`;

Although your use case seems flawed at a design level,this is possible

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="30dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/button_2"
android: layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
    android:id="@+id/second_buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/title_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

in order to set listeners for both buttons,

```
  findViewById(R.id.button1); //referring to first button
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.button_2)).findViewById(R.id.button_of_include) //referring to second button
```

**EDIT** based on the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28622471/3396197),a **crucial point** is giving an id to the parent layout containing the include.This would allow you to reference the layout and its child layout consequently. ie:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android: layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

            <include
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="80dp"
                 layout="@layout/include_layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. But if i want to bind same listener to some equals Views you may use tags. For example:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/map_button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tag="button"
                android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

Add method to get all views by tag:

```
private static ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, String tag){
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
        views.addAll(getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
    }

    final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
    if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
        views.add(child);
    }

    }
    return views;
}
```

Now just use it like

```
List<View> myViews = getViewsByTag(rootView, "button");
```

Answer (score 0):

**I did so**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
         />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android: layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

            <include
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="80dp"
                 layout="@layout/include_layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**inlcude_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1" // the same id
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**In my class**

```
Btn[0] = (Button).findViewById(R.id.button_1);      
Btn[1] = (Button)((RelativeLayout).findViewById(R.id.button_2)).findViewById(R.id.button_1);
```

**The result was to place two buttons with one id in one layout with one listener!**

Project https://github.com/kgsnick/TwoButtonWithOneId

Comment: So is this a different solution from what i had suggested?Because i see it and it seems quite similar.

Comment: The only difference is that I did @+id/button_1 in inlcude_layout.xml
Otherwise don't work.

Comment: Hmm.You could have told me about the error and I would have corrected it.Or atleast referenced my answer indicating you starting point.Nevertheless I shall include your change with due credits.